# Probability of area of a rectangle (uniform distribution)

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Given $X\sim U(0,2)$ and $Y\sim U(0,3)$ which are length and width of a rectangle (respectively). I want to find the probability of the area of the rectangle less than 1.

The hint is the joint density $f(x,y) = 1/6$ for $0\leq x \leq 2$ and $0 \leq y \leq 3$.

So, f(x,y) = 0, otherwise.

The answer is 0.4653, but never explained why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The joint distribution is depicted below together with the function $y=\frac1x$. $(X,Y)$ will have to fall in the pink area so that $XY<1.$
[image]

The probability we are looking for is the pink area times $\frac16$.

$$P(XY<1)=\frac16+\frac16\int_{\frac13}^2\frac1x\ dx=\frac16+\frac{\ln(6)}6\approx.4653.$$

Comment: One stupid question. Why 1/x ?

Comment: @Utopia: $\{XY<1\}=\{Y<\frac1X\}$. So $XY<1$ if $X=x$ and $Y=y$ for a pair of $x,y$ satisfying that $y<\frac1x.$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Try  to understand whether the following is true and evaluate it.

\begin{align}
Pr(XY < 1) = \int_0^2 \int_0^{\min(3,\frac1x)}f(x,y)dydx
\end{align}

Comment: May I ask why min(3,1/x) though?

Comment: theoretically we can write $\frac1{x}$ as well, however, once we go beyond $3$, $f(x,y)=0$.